# SQL Job Agent Fail to exec SSIS package with Cannot open the datafile Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS package to export out .crd file.

When I execute it from Integration Service, it works file. But if I call the package from SQL job agent I will get bellow error.

The funny think is if I change the connectionString from .crd to .csv it will just run fine from both Intergration Service and SQL Agent.

thanks.

Message

> Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Microsoft (R) SQL Server
>   Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.6020.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C)
>   Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  11:47:32 AM 
>   Error: 2016-03-30 11:47:32.70     Code: 0xC020200E     Source: Data
>   Flow Task 1 Destination - #_crd [2]     Description: Cannot open the
>   datafile "\export file path####.crd".  End Error  Error: 2016-03-30
>   11:47:32.70     Code: 0xC004701A     Source: Data Flow Task 1
>   SSIS.Pipeline     Description: Destination - #_crd failed the
>   pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC020200E.  End Error 
>   DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started: 
>   11:47:32 AM  Finished: 11:47:32 AM  Elapsed:  0.391 seconds.  The
>   package execution failed.  The step failed.

Comment: Perhaps SQL Agent does not have the correct security settings to write files to your selected path?

Comment: How do I check its security. what I was thinking is that the server is missing some packages or missing CardSpace application.